# netlogo turtles move directly to another turtle when in range

Tags: netlogo

This is a predator prey simulation with raptors and humans. I want the Raptors to move directly to the nearest human when in range. How to implement this in netlogo? Any suggestions?

Comment: Improve your question.

Comment: I think the close votes may come from people who aren't familiar with NetLogo, and as a result, can't tell that this is actually a clear and straightforward question.

Comment: @SethTisue is right.  (user3198608, I feel guilty saying this, but if you have a question of this kind that's entirely clear without any displaying source code, if you then add some of your source code anyway, people who don't understand NetLogo will be less likely to vote to close it.  That sounds like I'm telling you how to cheat, but perhaps it's reasonable if people are incorrectly voting to close due to not understanding the tool.  It won't work if the question is a bad question even with added source code: People who understand NetLogo may vote to close, or simply won't answer.)

Comment: It's better all around if questions include some source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you want a range of 5, and suppose you want the raptors to move one step towards the nearest human per tick.  Then:

```
ask raptors [
  let candidates humans in-radius 5
  if any? candidates [
    let target min-one-of candidates [distance myself]
    face target
    fd 1
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

To add an alternative to Seth's suggestion, if you were wanting the raptors to move immediately to the targeted human and then immediately eat them, you could try :

```
ask raptors [
   let candidates humans in-radius 5
   if any? candidates [
   let target min-one-of candidates [distance myself]
      move-to target
      ask target [die]
  ]
]
```

If you wanted the raptor to gain anything (energy, etc.) you could put it in a line between the move-to and ask target commands. If you wanted the human to do anything when eaten (yell out for other humans to run, etc.), you'd put it in the brackets after the ask target command but make sure to put it before die or else the die command executes first.